# Django Unleashed Cp.22: FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for User

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm following a tutorial book for Django (Django Unleashed) and I think there is a problem with the code when using newer versions of Django (i've read about problems with this chaper on amazon as well). So for future students of this book I ask this openly and in relation to the book.

For the creation of a custom user model the book suggests a user model that does not have a 'username' field. This Error occursd during `makemigrations`:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for User
```

There are other topics about this error on StackOverflow and they suggest that `django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin`needs the 'username' specified and therefore suggest adding an attribute called `add_fieldsets` to a class that inherits form `UserAdmin`. My question (so I dont have to get ahead of the code in the book in run into other problems) ... is it possible to create a custom user profile without specifiying a username and without the admin class? Here is my code so far:

User model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField('email adress', max_length=254, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('staff status', default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('active', default=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    joined = models.DateTimeField("Date Joined", auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.profile.get_absolute_url()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.profile.name
```

Usermanager

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(
            self, email, password, **kwargs):
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        is_staff = kwargs.pop('is_staff', False)
        is_superuser = kwargs.pop(
            'is_superuser', False)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            is_active=True,
            is_staff=is_staff,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
            **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(
            self, email, password=None,
            **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(
            email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(
            self, email, password,
            **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(
            email, password,
            is_staff=True, is_superuser=True,
            **extra_fields)
```

And I want to perform `makemigrations` without an error

Comment: If you "think there is a problem with the code [of the book]" you need to provide the code in question. Not all of the readers here have that book on their table. Otherwise it is a bit hard to answer your question "in relation to the book's code".

Comment: Here is the entire branch for the project exectly to where the error message appears. https://github.com/jambonrose/DjangoUnleashed-1.8/tree/19560085fc9e5d902c20968aed1293eca39dc5e8

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to use `AbstractUser` instead of the `AbstractBaseUser`

```
class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
```

or need declare `username` for your model, for example:

```
username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True)
```

Comment: Ok, I keep this solution in mind as I continue learning. But I do not think using the AbstractUser is the intention for that project although I do think that the desired behaviour could be created using your solution.